# How to compute $\displaystyle\sum_{k\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!4}}\!\!\binom{2014}{k}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have to compute:

$S=\binom{2014}{1}+\binom{2014}{5}+\binom{2014}{9}+...+\binom{2014}{2009}+\binom{2014}{2013}$

Could someone help me ?

Comment: What does the symbol $C^k_n$ mean when $k<n$? If you mean to find $\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n}{4k+1}$, then this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138928/sum-of-sequence-of-binomnr/1138954#1138954)will help you.

Comment: $C_{n}^k=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$

Comment: Note that the last term is just equal to the first term, the second is just equal to the one just before the last one etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!4}}\binom{2014}{k}&=&\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{2014}\binom{2014}{k}\left(i^{k-1}+(-1)^{k-1}+(-i)^{k-1}+1^{k-1}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{4}\left(-i(1+i)^{2014}+i(1-i)^{2014}+2^{2014}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{4}\left(i^2\cdot2^{1007}+i^2\cdot 2^{1007}+2^{2014}\right)\\&=&\frac{2^{2014}-2^{1008}}{4}\\&=&\color{red}{2^{2012}-2^{1006}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thanks you, but is there a solution not use  $i$ ? Sorry for my bad English =<